# Query Custom Post by taxonomy multiple categories

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, query

I need to query posts using certain taxonomy category, but more than one category of the taxonomy, as I can with posts categories..

For example, I have the **Portfolio** custom posts, and the **Project Type** to organize it (same as categories); So, we have **Animation, draw, icons and painting** types of project. I need to create an loop that will query **animations and painting** types only (query more than one king of portfolio type).

I thinked that tax_query would do it, but this tax_query selects only posts that are in the **animations and paintings at the same time**

My last code was:

```
$args['tax_query'] = array(
 array(
'taxonomy'  => 'project-type',
'field'  => 'id',
'terms'  => array(1,2) // don't work as I need, it's a exclusion)
)
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should give you an `OR` relationship:

```
$args['tax_query'] = array(
  array(
    'taxonomy'  => 'category',
    'field'  => 'id',
    'terms'  => array(1,2),
    'operator' => 'IN'
  )
);
```

As would this:

```
$args['tax_query'] = array(
  'relation' => 'OR',
  array(
    'taxonomy'  => 'project-type',
    'field'  => 'id',
    'terms'  => array(1)
  ),
  array(
    'taxonomy'  => 'project-type',
    'field'  => 'id',
    'terms'  => array(2)
  )
);
```

Be aware that that will become increasingly inefficient as you add more terms. It should perform tolerably with just two. The first version is neater and probably performs better in general, unless you need to search by multiple taxonomies.

Comment: Doesn't exist a flexible function to do this? Thought I'd add more terms as the categories are increasing...

Comment: @LeonardoGirardi : See the edit.